# Container not taking all the space in the page

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have started web dev not that long ago, and today I really tried to understand the basics of css and html, and I've got almost everything to work correctly. But I'm facing a problem that I can't seem to be able to solve by myself.

So here I am. I'm trying to replicate this design I did on figma, as a challenge for myself, and as a huge fan of Family Guy :

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRX1P.png)

So I started by learning how to create a css grid (I thought it was going to be usefull for each part of the page), then how to create a side bar and all of that. But there I am stuck :

My whole page is cranked into a tiny part :

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwaRG.png)

For further investigation, here's the grid in inspect mode :

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V3TE.png)

So how can I make it take the whole page like it should :

Here's my html and css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>FamilyGuy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
        <div class="card-1">
            <div class="card-image-container">
                <img class="card-image" src="./assets/img/Family_Guy_Season1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-title-container">
                <h3 class="card-title">Episode 1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-2">
            <div class="card-image-container">
                <img class="card-image" src="./assets/img/Family_Guy_Season1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-title-container">
                <h3 class="card-title">Episode 2</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #1E1E1E;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;

    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;

    grid-template-columns: [first] 18.23% [second] 2.6% [third] auto [fourth] 2.6% [fifth] auto [sixth] 2.6% [seventh] auto [eighth] 2.6% [ninth] auto [tenth] 2.6% [eleventh] 42.19%;
    grid-template-rows: [first] 2.78% [second] 2.78% [third] 5.28% [fourth] 13.89% [five] 3.06% [sixth] 19.44% [seventh] 2.6% [ninth] 19.44% [tenth] 2.6% [eleventh] 19.44% [twelveth] 2.6%;
}

div.navbar {
    background: #2F3136;

    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 1080px;

    grid-column-start: first;
    grid-column-end: span second;
    grid-row-start: first;
    grid-row-end: span twelveth;
}

div.card-1 {

    position: inherit;

    background: #2F3136;

    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 210px;

    grid-column-start: third;
    grid-column-end: span fourth;
    grid-row-start: sixth;
    grid-row-end: seventh;

    border-radius: 7.14%;
}

div.card-2 {

    position: inherit;

    background: #2F3136;

    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 210px;

    grid-column-start: fifth;
    grid-column-end: span sixth;
    grid-row-start: sixth;
    grid-row-end: seventh;

    border-radius: 7.14%;
}

div.card-image-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 158.68px;

    border-radius: 7.14%;
    padding: 7.14%;
    border-radius: 7.14%;
    width: 85.71%;
    height: 75.56%;
}

img.card-image {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 7.14%;
    justify-content: center;
}

div.card-title-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 41px;
}

h3.card-title {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: .2em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Please keep in mind that I just started static web dev recently, and that there may be a lot of errors in my code. I already apologize for the possible big noob error I could have done. This is actually my first time really trying to do something without any template or base code, so yeah, I'm kinda going blindfolded into this challenge. Already thanks for the help !

As stated. I've tried to replicate my figma design, but my body/html won't spread all the way on the page.

**UPDATE : looks like using :**

**`<div class="container" style="height: 852px">`**

**In the HTML, fixed my problem. Alhough, I'm not entirely satisfied of this, as it creates a scroll bar on the right. Which I'm not particularly a fan of. If any of you has ideas, I would gladly appreciate it.**

Answer (score 0):

**There** are two major problems with your code, apart from your issue:

1. The page is constructed as one large grid.  Espescially *CSS Grid* can be very intimidating creating such grid, where *Flexbox Layout* will probably feel more intuitive.

   - From your image it is clear that you have designed a main page with three main sub panels, each with its own distinct function. *Tools*, *Navigation & Image Grid* and *Preview*.
   - Each sub panel can be divided into several child panels and in some cases ever deeper nested panels.
2. Fixed units like `px` are your enemy, particularly when you want to design a responsive web page that can fit on various devices. Percentages based on a fixed value, while relative, will still eventually result in fixed values, e.g. 10% of 1920px will always be 192px. This will likely lead to cascading element size and positioning issues.

**Instead** of helping you with an issue in code you most likely will want to change one way or another, I took the liberty of creating a responsive base framework you can extend and modify to your needs:

- I divided your design into the nested panels mentioned before and removed all fixed units, except for a few in the media queries.
- Introduced a few Flexbox Layout shortcut (one letter) *attribute selectors* for easy 'on-the-fly' flexbox use.
- Element font sizes defined as parent dependent (`em` unit).
- Element sizes and spacing as root dependent (`rem` unit).
- Comments are in the CSS where applicable.
- Downloadable version of the code at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/XWBJbKp).

There is still a lot to do, I didn't create the entire page for you, but maybe this will give you a head start...

**Snippet**

```css
/* * { outline: 1px dashed white }/* for debugging only */

/********************************/
/* some convenient global rules */
/********************************/
 *          { box-sizing: border-box }
html, body  { width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
body        { min-height: 100vh; margin: 0 }

/* Linear equation y=mx+b using points p1(320,12) p2(1280,18) */
body { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.625rem) } /* responsive page font */

img {
    display: block;    /* removes whitespace below image */
    object-fit: cover; /* fill, but clip when lack of room */
    width: 100%;       /* width is leading */
    height: 100%;
}

iframe { border: none; max-width: 100% }

/* this and thats */
.icon  { display: inline-grid; place-items: center; padding: 0.25rem }
.big   { font-size: 1.75em; font-weight: bolder }
.small { font-size: 0.75em }


/* Easy flexbox shorcuts for on-the-fly use */
[F] { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap }
[R] { flex-direction: row    } /* flexbox default */
[C] { flex-direction: column }
[N] { flex-wrap: nowrap      } /* Flexbox default */

[F] > * { flex: 1 } /* allow flexbox kids to grow */

body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e; color: White;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header, footer, nav {
    display: flex; align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header { font-size: 1.5rem; justify-content: center }
footer { font-size: 0.8rem; justify-content: end    }
/***************/
/* end globals */
/***************/

/**********************/
/* Main app container */
/**********************/
.main {
    display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; /* fill parent */
    background-color: #2f3136;
}

/******************/
/* All sub panels */
/******************/
.sub {
    /* Flexbox column (of rows) container */
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;
    gap: 1rem; /* generic gap between various content panels */

    /* this will make a panel fit snuggly in a 320px or 360px device */
    min-width: min(18rem, 100%); /* = 288/16 or 100% */

    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}
.sub footer { margin-top: auto } /* move to bottom */
/* Footers are here to show height of panels */

/* panel spacing ratio 1:2:2 (comparable to grid 'fr' unit) */
/* when available and respecting .sub min-width   */
.sub.tools    { flex: 1 } /* allow to grow, where */
.sub.episodes { flex: 2 } /* flex-shrink = 1 and  */
.sub.preview  { flex: 2 } /* flex-basis  = 0%     */

/*******************/
/* Sub tools panel */
/*******************/
.search label { width: 100%; }
.search .icon { font-size: 1.5em }
.search input { font-size: 1em; width: calc(100% - 1.5em - 0.5rem) }
/* 100% minus icon size minus L/R icon padding */

/**********************/
/* Sub episodes panel */
/**********************/
.sub.episodes { 
    /* Define custom property for numer of image columns */
    --img-columns: 2; /* mobile first: 2 columns only */
    /* Overridden by  Media Queries */

    background-color: #36393f;
}

.navigation   { font-size: 1.75em }

/* Default for small devices < 720px */
.episode-grid {
    /* Use column value set by Media Queries */
    display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--img-columns), 1fr);

    gap: 0.5rem;
}
/* Media queries for gradually bigger devices, change as required */
/* Common use */
/*@media screen and (min-width:  721px) { .episode-grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) } } /* >  720px */
/*@media screen and (min-width: 1081px) { .episode-grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) } } /* > 1080px */
/*@media screen and (min-width: 1367px) { .episode-grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr) } } /* > 1366px */
/*@media screen and (min-width: 1921px) { .episode-grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr) } } /* > 1920px */

/* Custom property use */
/* Custom properties defined at parent element level, modified and used at element child level */
@media screen and (min-width:  721px) { .episode-grid { --img-columns: 3 } } /* >  720px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1081px) { .episode-grid { --img-columns: 4 } } /* > 1080px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1367px) { .episode-grid { --img-columns: 5 } } /* > 1366px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1921px) { .episode-grid { --img-columns: 7 } } /* > 1920px */

.card .small { text-align: center }

/*********************/
/* Sub preview panel */
/*********************/
.sub.preview .content { gap: 1rem }

.thumblist, .settings {
    gap: 0.25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #36393f;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.thumb {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #2f3136;
}

.card,.thumb          { border-radius: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem; background-color: #2f3136 }
:is(.card,.thumb) img { border-radius: 0.75rem }
```

```html
<!-- Main app container -->
<div class="main">

    <!-- Tools sub panel -->
    <div class="sub tools">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gEQ9EK6.png">
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="search" F C>
            <div class="bar">
                <label><input placeholder="Search"><span class="icon">&#9432;</span></label>
            </div>

            <div class="results">
                <div class="list" F C>
                    <div>result one</div>
                    <div>result two</div>
                    <div>result three</div>
                    <div>result four</div>
                    <div>result five</div>
                    <div>result six</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dots">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="more-tools" F C>
            <div class="tool one"  >tool one</div>
            <div class="tool two"  >tool two</div>
            <div class="tool three">tool three</div>
        </div>

        <footer>tools</footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Episodes sub panel -->
    <div class="sub episodes">
        <header></header>
        <div class="page-control" F C>
            <nav class="navigation" F>
                <div class="option"><span class="icon">&#9432;</span><span class="text">text</span></div>
                <div class="option"><span class="icon">&#9432;</span><span class="text">text</span></div>
                <div class="option"><span class="icon">&#9432;</span><span class="text">text</span></div>
                <div class="option"><span class="icon">&#9432;</span><span class="text">text</span></div>
            </nav>
            <div class="title">
                <div class="big">FamilyGuy.Com</div>
                <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ad wisi eius deserunt, cu iusto nonumes volumus usu, ne aeque aperiam saperet pro. Cu eum laudem sanctus, apeirian torquatos assentior mea ea, eos ut tantas altera sadipscing. Nam splendide voluptatum ad, integre quaeque definitiones mea et.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="episode-grid">
            <div class="card">
                <div F C>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/535?random=1">
                    <div class="small">byline</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div F C>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/535?random=2">
                    <div class="small">byline</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div F C>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/535?random=3">
                    <div class="small">byline</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div F C>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/535?random=4">
                    <div class="small">byline</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div F C>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/535?random=5">
                    <div class="small">byline</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <footer>episodes</footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Movie preview sub panel -->
    <div class="sub preview">
        <header>Live preview</header>

        <div class="content" F C>
            <div class="movie">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N-nJ3EMueyE"
                        title="Family Guy - Fight with the hologram (Season 21 Episode 6)"
                        frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="episode-selector">Episode selector</div>
            </div>
 
            <div class="highlights" F C>
                <div>Highlights</div>
                <div class="thumblist" F R>
                    <div class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/112?random=6"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/112?random=7"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/112?random=8"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/112?random=9"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="settings" F>
                <div class="subtitle" F C>
                    <p>Available Subtitles</p>
                    <label class="small">English <input type="checkbox"></label>
                    <label class="small">French  <input type="checkbox"></label>
                    <label class="small">Spanish <input type="checkbox"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="audio" F C>
                    <p>Available Audio tracks</p>
                    <label class="small">English <input type="checkbox"></label>
                    <label class="small">French  <input type="checkbox"></label>
                    <label class="small">Spanish <input type="checkbox"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>preview</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, got to admit, I wasn't expecting such a resourceful answer. Thank you so much for this really interesting answer, I will play with it, until I find something that suits my vision. But it's really amazing. 

I didn't know the existence of `flexbox` as I said I just started web dev, and therefore, I'm not really aware of all the technique that can be used to achieve this page.

I will keep learning about webdev, so I don't need to comeback here. 

Again thanks a lot for your very complete answer, I will try your solution as soon as I can. Thanks